# changing python tkinter ACTIVE

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to change the ACTIVE index in tkinter listbox:

```
listbox.selection_clear(0, 'end')
listbox.select_set(idx)
```

this only changes the highlighted line visually in UI but nothing changes in when I want to get:

```
listbox.get(tkr.ACTIVE)
```

what should I do to change the ACTIVE part of listbox

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved by using:

```
listbox.activate(idx)
```